# How can I make imports that will satisfy django-registration's 'activate' and 'register' calls?

Tags: python, django, django-registration, url-pattern

I have boilerplate code in my urls.py, taken from http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2011/01/14/setting-up-django-registration/:

```
                   url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>w+)/$',
                       activate,
                       { 'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend' },
                       name='registration_activate'),
                   url(r'^register/$',
                       register,
                       { 'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend' },
                       name='registration_register'),
```

This is crashing because I haven't defined or imported activate, and I expect it to raise similar issues about register.

How can I satisfy or adapt things so that the urlpatterns above will work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misread that page. Those aren't lines you add to your urlconf, they are *already defined* in django-registration's urls.py. You just need to include them as shown in step 4:

```
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
```

Comment: Thanks. I had *almost* implemented that, omitted the trailing slash, and assumed I had read the document wrong. Now it's working.